# Silverstripe - DataObject versioning and content archival

Tags: php, database-design, silverstripe

I am developing an extension to build custom itineraries. The idea is that user picks from a list of destinations and this is then added to the itinerary.

I am now solving the problem of what happens to historical itineraries if a destination is modified or deleted? Ideally, once the itinerary is complete, I would like to "freeze" the destination object and make a link to that version from the itinerary. Then, if a destination is removed or modified, the original itinerary still shows the information when it was all valid.

My thinking is to use [Versioned](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/class-Versioned.html) DataExtension, however, does this also deal with deletions?

Comment: deletions: why don't you simply prevent the destination object from being deleted, once it's referenced by some itinerary? 
modifications: doesn't it make sense that updated to destinations are also reflected in itineraries? if crucial data of a destination needs to be updated, you could simply create a new destination?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think it would make more sense to keep the destinations constant - as they are not going to change, only information contained in them could. Speaking for the client, they really only expect to update destinations and at the same time old bookings to be snapshot of that time. There is a notion of open/closed booking and once a booking is closed, it cannot be modified and that would be the timepoint to take the version.

Comment: i think that Versioned will hardly fit your needs then, as it's mostly about staging content (live/draft stages). for example, there's no built-in way in the ORM to associate one dataobject with some 'version' of another dataobject; and although there's a method 'get_version', saving data back to the returned dataobject will create a new version. i would try to separate data from the 'destination' object that is meant to be changed over time into separate dataobjects?